# Angular2 template tries to access async data before it's there

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, angular

I have a `DashboardComponent` that will display certain general data to the user. One such point of data is the number of Users we have on board.

I also have a `UserService` which has a method called `getUsers()` which returns JSON-mapped HTML response. So, in `DashboardComponent` I subscribe to this response:

```
this._uService.getUsers()
               .subscribe(
                 users => this.users,
                 error => alert(error)
               )
```

So now all I have to do is to display the length of this array in the DOM, with something like

```
We have {{users.length}} users on board!
```

(Or create a variable in `DashboardComponent` called `companyCount` and equate it to the `users` array length.)

The problem here is, when I do so, it tells me that users is as of yet undefined. Which is understandable as it's an observable and when it's trying to access it, it's not there. But I am not quite sure about the solution.

To me, the odd thing is that even if {{users.length}} (or even {{users[0]}}) gives an error, I can still use *ngFor #user of users, and display all the users nicely in a table, and it won't give me an error.

I found a way around, even though it's not what I want. I never actually get the users array but do this instead:

```
this._uService.getUsers()
               .subscribe(
                 users => this.userCount = user.length,
                 error => alert(error)
               )
```

and then in the template

```
<div *ngIf="userCount">We have {{userCount}} users on board!!</div>
```

So this div isn't displayed until the userCount is defined, meaning the subscription data has become available.

This does not look like a good solution to me, especially since on the dashboard I will eventually need to display stats with more complex calculations, tables etc.

What is the general approach to tackling this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Use the Elvis or safe navigation operator

```
{{users?.length}}
```

this way `length` is only evaluated when `user!= null`

Comment: That's a more elegant version of the solution I came up with... but let's say I wanna do a more complex calculation on the array (like adding all of its elements together and displaying the result) - how would I do it? Meaning, how would I display a result that needs a separate function to perform an operation on the array? --

Also, Can you give me a quick explanation as to why I can't display {{users[0]}} directly but can loop through users with the ngFor array just fine?

I am sorry I don't seem to be able to put in line breaks.

Comment: `users[0]` calls the `[]` operator on `users`. `null` doesn't have this operator therefore an exception is thrown.  Obviously `ngFor` itself checks whether `users != null` before it accesses properties. I don't really understand your question about the complex calcolation.

Answer (score 0):

The component is attempting to render before the content arrives.

You can't control when the data arrives because it's fetched asynchronously. Instead, use the [null object pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern) to set a default value (ie null object not undefined) so you have something to check against.

**service**

```
this.users = [];

this._uService.getUsers()
               .subscribe(
                 users => this.users,
                 error => alert(error)
               )
               .startWith(this.users);
```

*Note: `startsWith()` sets a null initial value (ie null object pattern), giving your template something to check against.*

**component**

```
this._uService.getUsers().subscribe(users => this.users = users)
```

*Note: There's no benefit to extracting and storing the length local to the component. It's best to avoid storing intermediate state as much as possible.*

**template**

```
<div *ngIf="users.length > 0">We have {{ users.length }} users on board!!</div>
```

If you want to do more operations on the users array wrap the group with a `<template>` element.

**template2**

```
<template [ngIf]="users.length > 0">
<div>We have {{ users.length }} users on board!!</div>
<div *ngFor="#user of users">
  {{ user.name }}
</div>
</template>
```

Only the `template` contents will display in the ContentView. If `users.length` isn't greater then 0 no additional checks are made and the `template` contents don't show up in the ContentView.

If you're working with complex objects that are loaded asynchronously via an observable, I've found that adding a `template` wrapper around the template group to be the cleanest approach.

Comment: Well I could find neither `.startsWith` nor `.startWith`. I get a compiler error when I try to implement that. And if I do *ngIf users.length>0, it's still trying to access users.length, which gives an error. It's fine if I do *ngIf users though.

Comment: @irenicus It's an import issue. To use rxjs operators (ex startWith) you'll have to install rxjs5 and import the operator with `import { startWith } from 'rxjs/operator/startWith';`. For a quick-and-dirty solution you could do what you already mentioned and just check against the existence of `users` since it won't exist until after the observer receives data.